# Customizing/Replacing the Windows CE 5.0 Taskbar?

Tags: windows-ce, taskbar

I'm currently getting my feet wet with Win CE 5.0 to update some code on an existing platform. We're interested in deploying a custom shell/home screen/application launcher as well and I had a couple questions:

1) We're running the standard CE shell and I'm assuming it can be customized because the source code is made available with Platform Builder. I was wondering how "painful" it would be to completely replace it with something like a status bar at the top of the screen (think iPhone). I was thinking task switching could then be handled by shortcut keys exclusively. I have my doubts about this.

2) If it can't be removed, can the taskbar be resized and moved to the top of the screen? We're basically trying to find a way to reserve the first 20 or so pixel rows at the top of the screen for our own status bar and prevent maximized application windows from drawing over top of it.

Thanks very much for the help.

-ksudeadeye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was happy and angry when I found the solution because it's more easy than I expect.
For 2) reserve space you need to do this:

```
RECT rc;
SetRect(&rc, 0, 25, GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN),GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETWORKAREA, 0, (void*) &rc, SPIF_SENDCHANGE);
```

With this code you reserve 25 pixels in the top of the screen.
:D

If you have doubts maybe [this](http://leo-luo.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=blogview&_c=BlogPart&partqs=cat%3DTrip%2520of%2520Mobile) can help you or [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/89d434c4-43cb-40a0-85b1-577543717add).

Good luck.

Comment: We ended up finding the SPI_SETWORKAREA flag as well during development, but it took some time. Hopefully this will spare someone else a few headaches. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

To hide the task bar is a simple registry change:

```
; Hide the windows tasbar by default.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shell\AutoHide]
""=dword:1
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shell\OnTop]
""=dword:0
```

As far as customizing, your own, that is a little more work, and not something I've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience with modifying the taskbar in CE 5.0. It is not an easy task, but the results can really add that personal touch to the device. I was tasked with adding a user mode second taskbar with a password dialog and a second type of shell notification to add icons to the user bar.

In the end, it is just standard Windows CE programming - the taskbar, notification tray, start button, etc. are just like any other windows in the CE environment.

You should start exploring here:
C:\WINCE500\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\EXPLORER\TASKBAR\taskbar.cpp

Be careful, clone your code, and be prepared for lots of debug cycles. This is more than 5000 lines of serious spaghetti code.